# How to blur without specific element

Tags: jquery

When I use blur event the input form clear. But I need blur event to include all html page except submit button.

html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="form">
     <table border="1">
       <tr><td></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" id="email" value="EMAIL ADDRESS_" maxlength="65"/></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="submit" value="" id="submit"/></td></tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email[type=text]').focus(function(){
         $(this).val("");

    }).blur(function(){
       if(this.value==""){
         $(this).val("EMAIL ADDRESS_");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad- I say"the input form clear",but I wanted to say, the input form filled with "EMAIL ADDRESS_"

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to accomplish. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many times spending for searching for right answer, i think this is best solution. I find the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349882/any-way-to-override-blur-if-submit-is-called-upon-in-jquery)

```
var setTimer = { timer: null }
    $('input,select').blur(function () {
        setTimer.timer = setTimeout(function () {
           $('#text').val('text');
        }, 200);
    });

    $('input,select').focus(function () {
        setTimer.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#text').val('');
        }, 200);
    });

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        clearTimeout(setTimer.timer);
        //do something
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something:

```
$('form input[type!=submit]').focus(function(){
     $(this).val("");

}).blur(function(){
   if(this.value==""){
     $(this).val("EMAIL ADDRESS_");
   }
});
```

Comment: Hello, I'd like that blur event doesn't affect the submit button.